# Resources to learn more about Android application design and development process/methodology

Tags: android, process, methodology

Anyone know of any good resources for learning more about the process involved in creating an Android application from scratch?

All the books I've seen discuss programming with Java and the Android API but I haven't found anything that talks about moving from concept through design and finally coding.

A long time ago I studied waterfall methodology and have a basic understanding of RAD type development.

Ideally what I'm looking for is something along these lines...

1. Basic idea for an app is presented, generating requirements
2. Process of designing the app, and deciding how data will be stored
   (UI, data, Class, entity diagrams etc.)
3. What to start coding first. UI, classes, DB?
4. Testing

It doesn't have to be complicated but I would like to see concrete detailed examples applied to a real Android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### mobiletuts+ App

Part 1: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/

Part 2: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/

http://code.google.com/p/android-mtlist-tutorial/

#### Notepad Tutorial

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

#### Movie search

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/10/android-full-application-tutorial.html

Comment: Also, not exactly what I was after but you mention some resources I have never seen before and they look like they will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably it could help: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html
And: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html 
For testing: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/index.html
They contains a very high level explanation, they are a good start for guidelines.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but some good resources all the same, thanks.